# For a smart thermostat, where do I attach the C wire to my furnace?

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat, furnace

I know I've seen several questions out there about getting a C wire for a smart thermostat, however after all the research I've done and people who have given me guidance so far I have still had no luck getting it to work the way I believe it should. I am most likely missing something simple as I am far from being an expert at either hvac systems or electrical wiring, but hopefully I can at least present the details well enough for someone smarter than me to help guide me in the right direction.

I got a smart thermostat and, before pulling the trigger, thought I did my homework in making sure I have a blue C wire available. It was also going from a similar model Honeywell thermostat to a smart version of the same thing (Lyric T5 being the new one), but of course when I got the new one and popped it onto the wall (these thermostats use the same universal wiring mount), no power. I then turned the furnace breaker off, then went to the furnace and found where the wiring for the thermostat goes and found quickly that the other end of the blue C wire was not connected to anything. I took off the panel to the internals of my furnace to hopefully find a control board that plenty of people online have shown, and there was no board but simply several transformers hooked together.

While I'm not an expert, with some help from some nice people I was able to (theoretically) determine where the C wire should go: I tried to join it to where the brown wire from the furnace joins the red wire that goes to my condenser as the brown wire appears to be the control wire. When I did that and turned the power back on, the thermostat came on but my condenser never would come back on. My thinking is that maybe the C wire to the thermostat is taking too much power that makes it so that it can't control the condenser? I ended up putting everything back the way I found it and everything still works thankfully, but I'm not sure what my next steps are from here.

Below are some links to some pictures that hopefully will give some more detail. If I need to add a transformer to provide separate 24v to the C and R wires to the thermostat, I would not know how to add that safely to my existing system (really want to avoid using a wall plug transformer if possible). Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Thermostat/Condenser Wiring at Furnace: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONgUT.jpg

Inside Furnace, no control board: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMxrC.jpg

Furnace Wiring Diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCvlr.jpg

Thermostat-side wiring: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fwgC.jpg

Edit: I actually found another post here that seems to have a similar wiring situation as me. The marked answer is essentially the conclusion I had come to, however implementing the solution as I described does not allow the condenser to come on anymore (the thermostat just flickers "cool on" indefinitely). I wanted to add this just for more detail if helpful:

[Where does my C wire go in this splice connection?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170788/where-does-my-c-wire-go-in-this-splice-connection)

Comment: Are you joining both the red return wire from the condensing unit and the C wire from the thermostat in with the brown C wire from your air handler?

Comment: Correct, I was attempting to wire nut those 3 wires together. I wasn't sure where else I could splice the C wire to as that brown wire from the air handler is labeled as the control wire. When those 3 wires are together, the thermostat turns on via the C wire but the condenser does not come on.

Comment: Maybe you need to use a wirenut that's one size larger, or just a new wirenut?

Comment: I did try a larger nut in that I swapped the larger white one with the smaller blue one currently in place, and I also tried stripping just a bit more of the brown wire as it was getting fairly frayed, but I haven't tried all new wire nuts all together yet. I'll try that next which will likely be tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: New wire nut did not make any difference. I tried both a wire nut as well as a 3 way push-in wire connector to splice the connection. With the push-in connector, I inserted just the brown from the air handler and the red from the condenser in the first and 3rd ports and turned the power back on to confirm it works normally. Then I turned power back off and put the blue C wire into the middle port, then turned power back on and it was the same symptoms as before: C wire works but condenser does not.

Comment: What make and model of smart 'stat are you using, and can you read us the labeling on your air handler's transformer please?

Comment: The new smart thermostat is the Honeywell Lyric T5, exact model number is RCHT8610WF2006

The transformer for the air handler, I'll do my best to read what it says though if it makes a difference, the common wire specifically isn't coming from what is labeled as the transformer as only the red wire seems to be coming from it: 

zettler, 
208/240v 50/60hz, 
blk-blu-org, 
24v 40va, 
brn-red, 
class b insulation, 
class 2 transformer

Comment: Hm.  The T5 only uses 1.5 of those 40VA.  Have you tried measuring the voltage across Y and C while the T5 is calling for cooling?